# Null pointer exception with jexcel while writing

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I need to append contents to an existing excel file using JExcel.

I am trying the following approach:

1. Read from existing workbook

   ```
   workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(errorFilePath));
   ```
2. Create writable workbook from exisitng workbook into a temp file

   ```
   if (!tempFile.exists()) {
      tempFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      tempFile.createNewFile();
   }
   newCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(tempFile, workbook);
   excelSheet = newCopy.getSheet(0);
   ```
3. Write to writable workbook(times is a writable cell format variable)

   ```
   Label label;
   label = new Label(column, row, stringData, times);
   excelSheet .addCell(label);
   ```
4. Close both exisitng and writable workbook->Delete exisitng workbook
   in finally block -> Rename temp file name to existing(now deleted) workbook name

   ```
    finally {
           if (null != newCopy) {
               newCopy.write();
               newCopy.close();
           }
           if (null != workbook) {
               workbook.close();
           }
           if (null != errorFile && errorFile.exists()) {
               errorFile.delete();
           }
           if (null != tempFile) {
               tempFile.renameTo(new File(errorFilePath));
           }

       }
   ```

   The problem is everything works fine for the first **run**(without redeploying).
   But whenever I change some java code, and the web application redeploys I get a null pointer exception while closing the newly created workbook(after writing).

I am getting the following stack trace(originating from line newCopy.write())

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
at jxl.write.biff.CellValue.getData(CellValue.java:259)
at jxl.write.biff.LabelRecord.getData(LabelRecord.java:141)
at jxl.biff.WritableRecordData.getBytes(WritableRecordData.java:71)
at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:147)
at jxl.write.biff.RowRecord.writeCells(RowRecord.java:329)
at jxl.write.biff.SheetWriter.write(SheetWriter.java:479)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.write(WritableSheetImpl.java:1514)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:950)
```

Java Version : 1.6

JExcel Version : 2.6.10

Windows 7

Comment: post your stacktrace of error

Comment: Are you generating xls or xlsx File ?

Comment: xls file...and stack trace is posted

Comment: Could you please try closing tempFile as well. Problem is that excel API usually keep a lock file for each edit and that may be preventing you to use the file again after redeploy.

Comment: tempFile is a file object(they do not have close methods.)
tempFile is passed as parameter to jexcel which creates newCopy out of it(see code snippet 2)
newCopy is closed in finally block

Answer (score 0):

Well, first suspicion is, in this line:

```
label = new Label(column, row, stringData, times);
```

you pass `null` argument(s).

Comment: I have checked...there are no null arguments... and _The problem is everything works fine for the first run(without redeploying). But whenever I change some java code, and the web application redeploys I get a null pointer exception while closing the newly created workbook(after writing)._
why only on redeploying?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. 
I was trying to add rows to the sheet dynamically in a loop using **insertRow**. After spending several hours it was probably a bug in the latest version of jxl api.
JXL api after 2.6.9 seem to have bug in insertRow. I switched to 2.6.9 from 2.6.12.